# Merging Rows in 2 XML document using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to some help to merge the 2 xml files using XSLT. Below I places some sample files.
Please follow the below

### First XML file (1.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rowset  xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Row>
    <Column0>1</Column0>
    <Column1>aaa</Column1>
    <Column2>a1</Column2>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Column0>2</Column0>
    <Column1>bbb</Column1>
    <Column2>b1</Column2>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Column0>3</Column0>
    <Column1>ccc</Column1>
    <Column2>c1</Column2>
</Row>

</rowset>
```

### Second XML file(2.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rowset  xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<Row>
    <Column0>3</Column0>
    <Column1>ddd</Column1>
    <Column2>d1</Column2>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Column0>4</Column0>
    <Column1>eee</Column1>
    <Column2>e1</Column2>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Column0>1</Column0>
    <Column1>aaa</Column1>
    <Column2>a1</Column2>
</Row>

</rowset>
```

### Expected Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rowset  xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Row>
    <Column0>1</Column0>
    <Column1>aaa</Column1>
    <Column2>a1</Column2>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Column0>2</Column0>
    <Column1>bbb</Column1>
    <Column2>b1</Column2>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Column0>3</Column0>
    <Column1>ccc</Column1>
    <Column2>c1</Column2>
</Row>

<Row>
    <Column0>3</Column0>
    <Column1>ddd</Column1>
    <Column2>d1</Column2>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Column0>4</Column0>
    <Column1>eee</Column1>
    <Column2>e1</Column2>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Column0>1</Column0>
    <Column1>aaa</Column1>
    <Column2>a1</Column2>
</Row>

</rowset>
```

---

Can any one help me...

---

Thanks,
JP

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, I tried in java by using DOM. But it is taking more time and facing java heap issue. 

Thanks,
JP

Comment: And I am very new to XSLT

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
  <xsl:param name="file1" select="document('Untitled1.xml')"/>
  <xsl:param name="file2" select="document('Untitled2.xml')"/>
  <xsl:key name="Column" match="*[starts-with(name(), 'Column')]" use="self::*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <rowset  xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$file1//*:Row"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$file2//*:Row"/>
      </rowset>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: No luck... it is failing at 8th line by saying invalid xpath expression

Comment: Have you changed this document('Untitled1.xml') with your XML URI path?

Comment: ERROR:  'file:///D:/temp/temp.xsl: line 8: Error parsing XPath expression '$file1//*:Row'.'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile style-sheet'
Invalid factory configuration

If i replaced "$file1//*:Row" with "$file1" then it merging complete document, but it is not not the expected output

Comment: I got the solution :) 
I replaced the 8th and 9th lines with below
 <xsl:copy-of select="$file1//*[name()='Row']"/>
 <xsl:copy-of select="$file2//*[name()='Row']"/>